# error configure and make qemu

Tags: compiling, make

I am new to ubuntu, I am using ubuntu 16.04
I got this error while installing qemu, after running sudo make

```
vl.c: In function ‘main’:

vl.c:2857:5: error: ‘g_mem_set_vtable’ is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]

     g_mem_set_vtable(&mem_trace);
     ^

In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/glist.h:32:0,

                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/ghash.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:50,
                 from /home/hsrf7/xv6/qemu/include/glib-compat.h:17,
                 from /home/hsrf7/xv6/qemu/include/qemu-common.h:43,
                 from /home/hsrf7/xv6/qemu/include/qemu/bitmap.h:15,
                 from vl.c:31:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmem.h:357:7: note: declared here

 void  g_mem_set_vtable (GMemVTable *vtable);
       ^

cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

/home/hsrf7/xv6/qemu/rules.mak:25: recipe for target 'vl.o' failed

make: *** [vl.o] Error 1
```

I used following steps.

1. Clone the IAP 6.828 QEMU git repository git clone `https://github.com/geofft/qemu.git -b 6.828-1.7.0`

2.Configure the source code

```
Linux: ./configure --disable-kvm --prefix=/home/hsrf7/qemu --target-list="i386-softmmu x86_64-softmmu"
```

3. `sudo make && sudo make install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add --disable-werror --enable-mc when running ./configure. That will not fix the problem but you will be able to compile. When running the VM you will get an error -- "custom memory allocation vtable not supported" but all seem to work ok for me

Comment: Reposted from a comment by Prof: *adding both `--disable-werror --enable-mc` didn't work. configure fails... apparently `--enable-mc` isn't a valid switch (couldn't find it when I grepped /.configure's help). I removed `--enable-mc` and then configure worked. I was then able to compile with a warning. I hope I'm not going to be in trouble down the line. What did `--enable-mc` do?*